# How to put a hyperlink in a innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 99%;">
<meta charset=utf-8>
<body style="height: 99%;">
    <table style="height: 99%;" align=center>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="sample" style="font-size:300%"></p>
                <script>
                    var myArray = [
                        'first',
                        'second',
                        'third',
                        'fourth'
                    ];
                    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)
                    var concat = myArray[rand]
                    concat = '&lt;a href=https://www.google.com/#q='+concat+'&gt;'+concat+'&lt;/a&gt;'
                    function random() {
                        document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = (concat);
                    }
                    random()
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvgQo.png

**Q:** how can I make the hyperlink work?

It just displays the html code

Comment: If you want it to parse as HTML, don't escape it.

Comment: In other words, you went out of your way to explicitly make it do this by using things like `&lt;`

Comment: it is html...just like you put in the rest of the page...so write it like html not text

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
concat = '&lt;a href=https://www.google.com/#q='+concat+'&gt;'+concat+'&lt;/a&gt;'
```

To:

```
concat = '<a href=https://www.google.com/#q=' + concat + '>' + concat + '</a>'
```